# Window open (silent)

Tags: javascript, window.open

would anyone know how to use JS window.open(...) but do it silently, i.e not actually open it so open check if it is able to be opened?

I am having to run script for a popup block check and I am almost there.  I don't want to browser to physically open the window, only to see if it can, and have no interference with the parent - no flicker, window.open then window.close, etc.

so something like:

```
if (!window.open(...)) {
    // code to say your have popup blocked
} else {
    ...
}
```

Its the last piece of my jigsaw but just cannot find the right bit of code to fit in the space!

Thanks

Comment: How can you determine if the `window` can be opened without opening the `window`?

Comment: If I knew that I wouldn't be asking the question!!  I just wont want to interfere or have any flicking with an open then close action

Comment: Not sure if it is possible. How would you verify the procedure?

Comment: Basically what it does is that after a button click, it goes off to try to link your FB account.  However, if users have popup blocked, the FB authentication doesn't happen because the browser is blocking popup.  We need to capture that on page load or at the very least on button click.  Its a promotion entry site where people answer a question but because of the popup blocking, they think site isn't working, where it is as people with no blocking is able to go through the procedure

Comment: What should occur if the browser is blocking popup?

Comment: A message saying 'Please allow popups' and this will include a link to a support site to say how to unblock them.  This is for non-IT people so need to be as helpful as possible

Comment: Have you tried using `error` handler? `var w = window.open("/path/to/resource"); w.onerror = function(){// do stuff}`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant but the code below checks if a new window has been opened.

```
let check = 0;
window.open("example.com");
check = 1;

if (check === 1) {
  // add code
} else {
  // add code
}
```

Comment: You can turn the first three lines of code into a function for convenience.

Answer (score -2):

```
function ok(){
    let check = 0;
    window.open("example.com");
    check = 1;
    return check;
}

if (check === 1) {
    // add code
} else {
    // add code
}
```